# Generic picker for FMCG analysis site?

Tags: website-design, selection, options

As it says in the title I'm working on a site that analyses FMCG market (basically anything you can find in supermarket). I need to redesign our current "picker". There are a number of pickers across our site for various things, for example "categories", "brands", "retailers", "dates" and a few others. It's very likely that we'll add more of them so ideally I need something generic that everyone will recognise. Here's what we currently have:

[image]

I quite like the idea of "+" and "-" icon, and the smart text underneath but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

It your example it is quite obscure what the user can select or deselect.

Maybe you want to display a list in some form or another and use checkboxes.

*An example in Gmail*

[image]

**Generic is not always a good idea.** What makes sense is context so depending on what you are picking the UI can be different (most of the time it should be different in fact).

Exemple with Dates in your example: 
does the user really has to select/deselect a date? Can't she simply define it in an appropriate input?

Comment: +1 I do like your thoughts but unfortunately we can't simplify our picking method to a dropdown list as the things that people set are often very granular. In addition to this sometimes you may have hundreds of thousands of options (brands for example) and the interface for choosing them is quite complex. But I do agree that generic is not always a good idea, that is a good point and I guess I have to just mock up some ideas and decide which works best. Thanks!

Comment: ;-) see you soon then.

Answer (score 0):

The '+' and '-' seem not very intuitive to me. I guess you're looking for something like this:

**Categories** *Show all*

[X] Category 1

[_] Category 2

**Brands** *Show all*

[_] Brand 1

[_] Brand 2

**Dates** *Show all*

(_) Last 30 days

(*) Last 90 days

using checkboxes for multiple selects and radio buttons for mutual excluding selections. This is a pattern that is found in a lot of platforms and ecommerce applications (eg., eBay), and which people are used to.